# Wanna try some looping for tag <option></option>

Tags: php, html, sql, loops

Here, i'am had some case that i thought that are uniq for me.
this the problem, i want to looping some tag 
3 times. The loop is work, but when it was input to database...
just 1 loop that worked.

Here the Screenshot,

[The value of loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMzC8.png)

[Result of loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4IQI.png)

```
<td>
    <label for="baris">Baris</label>
    <select name="baris">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <?php 
            for ($i2=A; $i2 < F; $i2++) { 
                echo "<option name='".$i2."'>".$i2."</option>";
            }
         ?>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <label for="kolom">Kolom</label>
    <select name="kolom">
        <?php 
            for ($i3=1; $i3 <= 10; $i3++) { 
                echo '<option name="'.$i3.'">'.$i3.'</option>';
            }
         ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

also this code for input to database

```
<?php     
                if(isset($_POST['masukan'])){
                    $nama = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nama']);
                    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
                    $jk = htmlspecialchars($_POST['jk']);
                    $notlp = htmlspecialchars($_POST['notlp']);

                    $queryinput = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE tb_customer 
                                                        SET nama='$nama',
                                                            email='$email',
                                                            notlp='$notlp',
                                                            jk='$jk'

                                                        WHERE id_cust='$id_cust1'    
                                                        ");

                    $querytampil = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tb_customer WHERE id_cust ORDER by id_cust desc limit 1");
                    $dcus = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querytampil);
                    $id_cust = $dcus['id_cust'];

                    $querytampil2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT max(num_ticket)AS num  FROM tb_ticket");
                    $dnumti = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querytampil2);
                    $num_ticket = $dnumti['num'];
                    $hasil = $num_ticket + 1;

                    for ($i5= 1; $i5 <= $p; $i5++) { 

                    $baris = htmlspecialchars($_POST['baris']);
                    $kolom = htmlspecialchars($_POST['kolom']);
                        if($queryinput){
                            $id_flight = $data['id_flight'];
                            $queryinput2 = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO tb_ticket VALUES('','$id_cust','$id_flight','$hasil','','','','','$id_dest','$id_ori', '$baris', '$kolom')");

                            if ($queryinput2) {
                                $querytampil3 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tb_ticket order by num_ticket desc limit 1");
                                $dtick = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querytampil3);
                                $nt = $dtick['num_ticket'];
                                echo "<script>alert('Succes.')</script>";
                                echo '<script>window.location="pembayaran.php?num_ticket='.$nt.'&&id_cust='.$id_cust.'"</script>';
                            }else{
                            echo "<script>alert('Your data cannot send.')</script>";
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo "<script>alert('Your data cannot send, please check your input data.')</script>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Bad engslish sorry*

Comment: Please dont post pictures of code. The raw text is much better

Comment: When you post the code, please also include the stuff that actually writes to the database.

Comment: that actually work... but after input to database just 1 loop that work

Comment: @IsThisJavascript My mistake, mistook the warnings for errors. Silly me :)

Comment: @Alberiansyah we're still missing how you input your data into the database. All this code does is just output some text.

Comment: Do you mean you are only getting **1** value back from each of your dropdowns?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript haha, that the problem the loop succes, but input data just 1. lol

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes.

Comment: Is this issue in your insert or update query? Edit: it must be since that's the only query that makes use of your $_POST

Comment: have you solution? i am still stuck at here, actually i just fun trying and get a case like this.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript maybe the code is work, but the value returned for me just 1, not 3

Comment: hm, i'am still think :/ . @IsThisJavascript

Comment: I fully believe the issue is because of `for ($i5= 1; $i5 <= $p; $i5++) { `. You will probably see the one value that gets set is the last option you choose and that's because you're overwriting $_POST values. Don't overwrite variables you need, instead construct a request array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got this correct; it's because you are not setting your html variables as an array.

The first changes you need to make are within your view page..

`<select name="baris">` -> `<select name="baris[]">`

`<select name="kolom">` -> `<select name="kolom[]">`

This sets your `$_POST['baris']` and `$_POST['kolom']` as arrays.

Since you're already looping...

```
for ($i5= 1; $i5 <= $p; $i5++) { 
    $baris = htmlspecialchars($_POST['baris']);
    $kolom = htmlspecialchars($_POST['kolom']);
```

This stuff now needs to access the relevant array... And becomes...

```
for ($i5= 1; $i5 <= $p; $i5++) { 
    $baris = htmlspecialchars($_POST['baris'][$i5]);
    $kolom = htmlspecialchars($_POST['kolom'][$i5]);
```

Comment: Awesome to hear please press the tick under the upvote/downvote buttons so this thread can be solved && closed :)

Comment: Just a friendly notice; `htmlspecialchars` shouldn't be used for database sanitation. Please give this topic a read [on how to prevent mysqli injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)